# What does the "release" stage in Twelve-Factor App correspond to?

Tags: docker-swarm

In Docker Swarm project, what does the "release" stage of [12 factor app](https://12factor.net/build-release-run) correspond to?

From my understanding the "docker build" corresponds to *build* stage, and the image this produces does *not* constitute a release (because it has yet to be combined with an environment's config).

Here is the official description:

> A codebase is transformed into a (non-development) deploy through
>   three stages:
>
> The build stage is a transform which converts a code repo into an
>   executable bundle known as a build. Using a version of the code at a
>   commit specified by the deployment process, the build stage fetches
>   vendors dependencies and compiles binaries and assets.
>
> The **release**
>   stage takes the build produced by the build stage and combines it with
>   the deploy’s current config. The resulting release contains both the
>   build and the config and is ready for immediate execution in the
>   execution environment.
>
> The run stage (also known as “runtime”) runs
>   the app in the execution environment, by launching some set of the
>   app’s processes against a selected release.

They further clarify:

> Every release should always have a unique release ID, such as a
>   timestamp of the release (such as 2011-04-06-20:32:17) or an
>   incrementing number (such as v100). Releases are an append-only ledger
>   and a release cannot be mutated once it is created. Any change must
>   create a new release.
>
> Builds are initiated by the app’s developers whenever new code is
>   deployed. Runtime execution, by contrast, can happen automatically in
>   cases such as a server reboot, or a crashed process being restarted by
>   the process manager. Therefore, the run stage should be kept to as few
>   moving parts as possible, since problems that prevent an app from
>   running can cause it to break in the middle of the night when no
>   developers are on hand. The build stage can be more complex, since
>   errors are always in the foreground for a developer who is driving the
>   deploy.